# Only first fragment showing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an activity with 2 Fragment

- First fragment show a list of galleries using a LisFragment
- Second fragment show the preview images of the gallery selected in the first fragment

When I declare the fragment in the view it works. But now I want to manage fragment dynamically :

```
GalleriesFragment gfs = new GalleriesFragment();
GalleryFragment gf = new GalleryFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.layout_m,gfs);
ft.add(R.id.layout_m,gf);
ft.commit();
```

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:id="@+id/layout_m">
</LinearLayout>
```

When doing this only the first fragment added is shown, I tried to invert their order when adding fragment...

When I was working on the layout I could set my fragment width with:

```
android:layout_width="400dp"
```

Now I have 2 questions :

1. How can I make my 2 fragments to display?
2. How can I set the width (programmatically?) of the 1st fragment and the second to fill the remaining width?

Thanks for your help!

PS:

`GalleriesFragment` doesn't have a layout and is not overriding `onCreateView`, but has an `ArrayAdapter` returning view like this for each rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:contentDescription="preview"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texttitre"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:background="@layout/roundcorner"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Title here" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
            android:text="description" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

GalleryFragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Update 2 :

I added an `onCreateView` in my `GalleriesFragment` class :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lparams =  new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        container.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

This fixes the first fragment's  width, but the second one is still not showing...

Comment: Can you add the layouts for those fragments?

Comment: added the layout for GalleryFragment, 
Galleries fragment don't have a layout but a ArrayAdapter to fill it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make my 2 fragments to display ?

Your current approach will make the first fragment supplied to the `add` method to take all the space of your container layout. One solution is to use a layout that reserves space for each of the two fragments that get added, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_m"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in code:

```
ft.add(R.id.frame1, gfs);
ft.add(R.id.frame2, gf);
ft.commit();
```

> How can I set the width (programmatically ?)of the 1st fragment and
>   the second to fill the remaining width?

Fragments are not just ordinary views but one way to do that is to use your single `LinearLayout` layout file and set the `LayoutParams` of the fragment's view in `onActivityCreated`:

```
getView().setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Of course this will make your fragments to be tied to the parent container, also I don't know how well this will work in the overall fragment system.